# getting a list of data in a specific manner using iterator

Tags: java

I am having these list of data from the database

```
Level 1
Level 2
Level 3
will get 100 points
will get 200 points
will get 300 points
```

My java code:

```
List ln5 = readDB(iStepNumber, status, query5);
Iterator itr5 = ln5.iterator();
while (itr5.hasNext()) {
   String Levels1 = (String) itr5.next();
   String LevelsDescription1 = (String) itr5.next();
   String Levels2 = (String) itr5.next();
   String LevelsDescription2 = (String) itr5.next();
   String Levels3 = (String) itr5.next();
   String LevelsDescription3 = (String) itr5.next();
}
```

I need to get the data as follows,

```
Level 1
will get 100 points
Level 2
will get 200 points
Level 3
will get 300 points
```

Any Suggestion Plz?

Comment: please provide full code, we do not see where you are printing the output out

Comment: I am trying to understand what you wanna do here. You are putting in all everything in the loop inside the same variable called levels1 itself?

Where are you using this data? Are you printing it? if yes, can we get that code?

Comment: your code cannot compile, your use many times the same name variable

Comment: Its not level 1,assume,it may stored in some other new variable @ar

Comment: @ArvindSasikumar

Comment: Give us your output statements mate, then we can exactly suggest what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Suggestion 1 :** Change the way you stock your datas. It's a strange way to do it

**Suggestion 2 :** If you can't change, then use a for on the list

```
for(int i = 0;i< ln5.size()/2;i++){
    System.out.println(ln5.get(i));
    System.out.println(ln5.get(i+ln5.size()/2));
}
```

Comment: Cool ! Be carreful to test if ln5 is pair, in order to avoid outOfBoundException